# What Is getInstance Method in MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, materialize

I only spent a few hours using the MaterializeCSS framework, and I found code that I don't think I understand and there might not be an explanation in the documentation, can you explain it to me what is the function of the getInstance () method ?

```
let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".sidenav");
M.Sidenav.getInstance(elems).close();
M.Sidenav.init(elems);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getInstance` returns the component and all the data available for it - on which we can use provided methods that vary from component to comonent.

**#1** `var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');`

This selects all elements with a class of sidenav. If we log `elems`, we see that it is a nodelist. You will likely only ever have a single `sidenav`, but you can imagine if were were looking at select inputs, we might have more than one on the page.

**#2** `var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems)`;

This initializes the component. In my codepen I log `instances[0]` - remember that we are selecting potentially multiple elements, and so we need to access them via nodelist index. `[0]` returns the first instance, or the first sidenav in this case.

Say you had more than one sidenav, and you wanted to run a method on one of the sidenavs, say to open it. To do that we need to get the specific instance. So we could use the nodelist index - `instances[0].open()` - or, we could be more explicit:

**#3** `var elem = document.querySelector('#mobile-demo')`;

This gets a single sidenav via ID (note the use of `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`).

**#4** `var instance = M.Sidenav.getInstance(elem);`

This gets the specific instance and if we look at the log for `instance`, we can see that it is identical to using `instances[0]`.

We can now run `instance.open()`, or get all kinds of data by inspecting the returned object. Logging `instance.options` displays the options used to init - in this case none - so we see the default values returned.

Check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/ExammVr) and look at the logs.